# Change background of the button in Action Bar, Android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm having a problem, I'm developing a app and I want to change background color of the buttons of the Action Bar. I have made follow it:

In my menu.xml, I have this code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".main" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_carrito"
        android:title="@string/action_example"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_carrito"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And my styles.xml, I have this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/darker_green</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Both buttons catch this background color. But I only want to put it for the button with id is "@+id/action_carrito". I hope somebody can to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to create a `action_carrito_bg.xml` which is a `layer-list` under your `drawable` folder, that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darker_green"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_carrito"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then remove `MyActionButtonStyle` from `styles.xml`, and set that drawable as icon of the menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".main" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_carrito"
        android:title="@string/action_example"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_carrito_bg"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: first, thanks for your help. I did this, but I noticed that the button gets a "padding", I think this is the default. My goal is that the background color takes the space without "padding". Add a photo:

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47967238/Screenshot_2014-11-08-12-05-06.png)[/link]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add this line `<size android:height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" android:width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>` inside `<shape></shape>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to add your code but does not work, why? Could this be why I am using a Fragment? Thanks.

Comment: Exceptios is:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx, PID: 23624
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/action_carrito_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020057 and Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
Do I have to give one height and width the ActionBar?, Sorry, I'm enough rookie.

Comment: What if you will try to add `<size android:height="45dp" android:width="45dp"/>` inside  `<shape></shape>` tag ?

Comment: Thanks @Romadja, but doesn't work. I will change style. If I find a fix, I'll edit the comment :)

Comment: How can I achieve this in a selector? my goal is to add a layer on action menu button when it in pressed state